# Oauth2 No grant found for state in flask and oic.oauth2 package

Tags: python, authentication, flask, oauth-2.0, cloud-foundry

I am trying to implement Oauth2 authentication using the OpenID connect workflow with the Cloudfoundry UAA as the backend authentication provider in a python flask application using oic.oauth2.

I am encountering an issue where I encounter "No grant found for state" error when trying to do the access token request even though I can successfully curl and obtain the access token via POST

```
curl -k 'https://172.17.0.114:8443/oauth/token' -i -X POST -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -d 'client_id=ga4gh_server&client_secret=ga4gh_server&grant_type=authorization_code&response_type=id_token&code=1n3ILw&state=CyBAFDwl79YU19lCEdODalMD&token_format=opaque&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2F172.17.0.107%2Fga4gh%2Foauth2callback'
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Cache-Control: no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Fri, 15 Jul 2016 20:45:05 GMT

{"access_token":"2f57ef6dd73c482cac5aa7b8826ba8b7","token_type":"bearer","id_token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImxlZ2FjeS10b2tlbi1rZXkiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.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.bDA3fLRMgtcPuUMw6laV89MwDqsIRkWi4-l0qvoN7qA","refresh_token":"2f57ef6dd73c482cac5aa7b8826ba8b7-r","expires_in":43199,"scope":"openid","nonce":"ajhs3gev4t8TBDB1zTvBbJJP","jti":"2f57ef6dd73c482cac5aa7b8826ba8b7"}
```

The flask application generates a 24 key random 'nonce' and 'state' to identify itself but it seems like 'state' is not getting parsed correctly causing my access token request to fail :(.

Here is the code that deals with the oauth2callback, it is implemented using pyoidc

```
if app.oidcClient is None:
    raise exceptions.NotImplementedException()
response = dict(flask.request.args.iteritems(multi=True))
#aresp = app.oidcClient.parse_response(
#    message.AuthorizationResponse,
#    info=response,
#    sformat='dict')
sessState = flask.session.get('state')
#respState = aresp['state']
respState = sessState
code = flask.request.args.get('code')
#if (not isinstance(aresp, message.AuthorizationResponse) or
#        respState != sessState):
#    raise exceptions.NotAuthenticatedException()
if respState != sessState:
     raise exceptions.NotAuthenticatedException()

args = {
    "client_id": app.oidcClient.client_id,
    "client_secret": app.oidcClient.client_secret,
    "grant_type" : 'authorization_code',
    "response_type" : 'token',
    #"code" : aresp['code'],
    "code" : code,
    "redirect_uri": app.oidcClient.redirect_uris[0]
}
atr = app.oidcClient.do_access_token_request(
    scope=["openid"],
    state=respState,
    request_args=args)

if not isinstance(atr, message.AccessTokenResponse):
    raise exceptions.NotAuthenticatedException()

atrDict = atr.to_dict()
if flask.session.get('nonce') != atrDict['id_token']['nonce']:
#if flask.session.get('nonce') != atrDict['nonce']:
    raise exceptions.NotAuthenticatedException()
key = oic.oauth2.rndstr(SECRET_KEY_LENGTH)
flask.session['key'] = key
#app.tokenMap[key] = aresp["code"], respState, atrDict
app.tokenMap[key] = code, respState, atrDict

# flask.url_for is broken. It relies on SERVER_NAME for both name
# and port, and defaults to 'localhost' if not found. Therefore
# we need to fix the returned url
indexUrl = flask.url_for('index', _external=True)
indexParts = list(urlparse.urlparse(indexUrl))
if ':' not in indexParts[1]:
    indexParts[1] = '{}:{}'.format(socket.gethostname(), app.myPort)
    indexUrl = urlparse.urlunparse(indexParts)
response = flask.redirect(indexUrl)
return response
```

Upon success auth server login, the server will be redirected to the callback url with the following parameters.

```
https://172.17.0.107/ga4gh/oauth2callback#token_type=bearer&id_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImxlZ2FjeS10b2tlbi1rZXkiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.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.tXC1kP2nT_8cLaM0Gyk_rcDEetqIo39J_C3jtulTDm4&code=1n3ILw&state=CyBAFDwl79YU19lCEdODalMD&expires_in=43199&nonce=ajhs3gev4t8TBDB1zTvBbJJP&jti=0f6522ca757e43beb59e60cb2d3afcfb
```

However, it seems like I cant parse the state arg off this callback url for some reason in order to proceed with my access token request.

Any idea as to how to fix this would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you very much!

Comment: You have `https://172.17.0.107/ga4gh/oauth2callback#...`, it should be `https://172.17.0.107/ga4gh/oauth2callback?...`.

Comment: Hi Amit, the Cloud foundry documentation shows that it actually starts with #. Please refer to here https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/api/uaa/#with-authorization-code-grant. I also tested by adding / to the end of the callback route so it becomes like oauth2callback/#token_xxx but it gives me a infinite loop instead.

Comment: Hi Amit, after further investigation, I seem to have located the issue, the problem is being with the # anchor. flask get requests ignore all anchor comments after # so I could not obtain the request.args on the server response from after the authorization request. Unfortunately, looks like I will have to use javascript to modify theresponse from the request a bit to obtain it via GET and then should be able to resolve the issue.